# Shortest possible way to write this ruby segment

Tags: ruby

What's the shortest possible way to rewrite the below snippet?

```
print @b > @d ? ( @d+=1 ;"S" ) : @b < @d ? ( @d -= 1; "N" ) : "";

print @a > @c ? ( @c+=1 ; "E") : @a < @c ? ( @c -= 1; "W" ) : "";

puts" "
```

The first and second lines are identical in structure but with different variables, so some kind of macro expansion could be useful if the object is to keep number of bytes to a minimum. Is there any macro expansion style syntax supported by ruby? Something like in c or c++.

I found this example of the fizzbuzz challenge inspiring for short code https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/99787, but don't fully understand the syntax.

EDIT: For Cary and others to give a full context the full code of my program is as follows after a few suggestions.:

```
@a,@b,@c,@d=gets.split(" ").collect{|x|x.to_i}; 
do 
print"SN[t=@b<=>@d,1];
@d+=t print"EW"[t=@a<=>@c,1];
@c+=t 
end
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: @mu, I'm not so sure. Code Golf generally permits answers to be in any language, but the OP specifically wants Ruby. Is there a rule that such a question cannot be on SO?  Also, everyone can use a bit of fun.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I wouldn't expect to see code like that in "real" software (and if I did I'd be reaching for my firing stick) so I don't think this is the right place for it, I tend to see SO as a home for the more professional side of things. The FAQ even says "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" and I don't see anything practical about these sorts of games. Shame I can't tell you to get off my lawn :)

Comment: @mu, that's a point, but there are plenty of answers on SO that contain Ruby code that is highly educational but wouldn't make it through a software review.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Code Golf! Here's a possibility:

```
print ['',?S,?N][t=@b<=>@d]; @d+=t
puts  ['',?E,?W][t=@a<=>@c]+' '; @c+=t
```

Edited to steal an idea from @Steve.

Comment: I get 

"String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)"

for the above. I forgot to mention that the original code is wrapped in between a do end loop. Does that impact the way that the shortened code is written??

Comment: Metal, I suggest you edit your question to give values or the four instance variables, so that we can compare answers.

Comment: After seeing @Steve's answer, I see I could have written `print ['',?S,?N][t=@b<=>@d]; @d+=t`, but since this doesn't have to pass a code review...

Comment: Metal, you were right, I had a bug, which I believe I've fixed, taking a page from @Steve's answer. In fact, Steve and I seem to be converging.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this...

```
print " SN"[@b<=>@d];@d+=@b<=>@d
puts " EW"[@a<=>@c];@c+=@a<=>@c
```

edited to steal an idea from Cary

```
print " SN"[t=@b<=>@d];@d+=t
puts " EW"[t=@a<=>@c];@c+=t
```

Comment: Yes, " SN" is preferable to `[" ","S","N"]` and the `;` seems needed.